# Creating a particular chart in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a chart using ggplot and R.

The chart is of # of git commits per person by hour of day. There are several people, so I want the chart to look something like this:

[image]

Example row:

```
Name,5am,6am,7am,8am,9am,10am,11am,12pm,1pm,2pm,3pm,4pm,5pm,6pm,7pm,8pm,9pm,10pm,11pm,12am,1am,2am,3am,4am
Tommy Hilfiger,6,11,4,12,15,43,94,77,52,82,83,93,73,56,43,25,19,13,8,17,1,11,12,6
```

However, I'm pretty stuck doing this on R. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your data frame (df) looks like:

```
Time    Commits    Name
1am     3          Hilfiger
2am     5          Hilfiger
3am     1          Hilfiger
1am     1          Nike
2am     2          Nike
3am     3          Nike
```

I think this code should work:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Time,y=Commits)) + geom_bar() + facet_wrap(~ Name)
```

I wrote this answer from my phone off the top of my head, I'll double check my answer tomorrow when I have access to R.

Comment: thanks - yeah, you're right, I eventually worked out it's because the data wasn't formatted in the R-friendly way, so the dataframe wasn't right. then it was:

`x<-qplot(data=commits,x=Time,y=Commits, geom="bar")`
`x<-x + facet_wrap(~Name, scale="free_y")`